# Вопросительный и восклицательный знак

Tags: пунктуация

Обычно, когда мы обозначаем вопрос с восклицанием, то пишем ?! - именно в такой последовательности. А может ли эта последовательность меняться? То есть, может ли быть наоборот: !? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, в правилах пунктуации такого изменения порядка знаков не предусмотрено.
На самом деле сочетание "?!" следует рассматривать как единый знак, оговоренный "Правилами орфографии и пунктуации" именно в таком виде, поэтому искать возможности для иного порядка просто бессмысленно. Если бы это два разных знака, каждый из которых ставится по своим, самостоятельным соображениям, то теоретически поиск иного порядка был бы не лишен цели. Хотя все равно трудно представить, зачем такое может понадобиться.

Answer (score 1):

В экспериментальной авторской пунктуации возможно всё: и 8-16 точек подряд, и (-...-), и страшно подумать что. Но к правилам пунктуации это, конечно, не имеет отношения.